# Using BasicAuth with SolrJ Code

Tags: java, solr

I have just set up the Basic Authentication Plugin in Solr 6.4.2 on SolrCloud, and I am trying to modify my SolrJ code so that the code can go through the authentication and do the indexing.

I tried using the following code from the Solr Documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Basic+Authentication+Plugin.

```
SolrRequest req ;//create a new request object 
req.setBasicAuthCredentials(userName, password); 
solrClient.request(req);
```

However, the code complains that the req is not initialized.

If I initialized it, it will be initialize as null.

```
SolrRequest req = null;//create a new request object 
req.setBasicAuthCredentials(userName, password); 
solrClient.request(req);
```

This will caused a null pointer exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How should we go about putting these codes, so that the error can be prevented?

Regards,
Edwin

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable req with null value which is the result of NPE.

```
SolrRequest req = null;//create a new request object 
req.setBasicAuthCredentials(userName, password);
```

which should be like this

```
SolrRequest req = new SolrRequest( method, path );
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin for your reply. But I'm getting this error when I put in that statement:
'Cannot instantiate the type SolrRequest`
I'm using Solr 6.4.2 with Java 8.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the class itself but that is an abstract so you need to look for library that suits your need. check this http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.METHOD

Comment: According in the documentation 
`new QueryRequest(new SolrQuery("*:*"));`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The NullPointerException is not coming out now, but the SolrJ is still not able to get authenticated. I'm still getting Error Code 401 even after the code is run.